# Time required to reach the ground in Horizontal and Vertical projection

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

I throw a pen vertically with zero velocity from height $H$. Again, I throw it as horizontal projection with velocity $V$ from same height. Is time required by the pen in both cases to fall in the ground be same?

Many assume that as the horizontal projectile is going to travel more distance in horizontal direction, so it has to take more time to reach the ground.But, my following mathematical analysis does not support so.Moreover, it's not intuitive either...

MY ASSUMPTION:

For vertical falling,
$$
H=\frac{1}{2}gt^2
$$

For horizontal projection,
$$
H=V\sin 0°+\frac{1}{2}gt^2=\frac{1}{2}gt^2
$$

So, we see that both are same...

Now, I  want to know whether my approach is correct or not ?And how can I think it conceptually...with a thought experiment...

Comment: So what's the problem? Please post your doubts and show some research skills. Also if you are throwing a pen with zero velocity, logically you are dropping it.

Comment: The equation for H with initial velocity V is: $H=Vt+0.5gt^2$. So where does $Vsin 0^0 $ comes from?

Comment: In horizontal projectile,vertical component of velocity is Vsinα,where α=0°...And I want to know whether my assumption us correct or not...And btw the latter part of the question shows my research work...

Comment: So yes. In both cases you have a free fall with vertical $V_0=0$ and only the vertical axis determines the fall time.

Comment: Hi Nehal Samee. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the time taken to fall to the ground is the same in both cases, and we can see this with a simple thought experiment.

Suppose you are stationary at some height $h$ above the ground, while I am travelling past you at some speed $v$. You drop the stone vertically downwards and as you say the time it takes to hit the ground is given by:

$$ h = \tfrac{1}{2}gt^2 $$

Let's look at the fall of the stone from your perspective. It looks like this:

[image: Your frame]

But now consider what the fall of the stone looks like from my perspective. Relative to me you and the stone are travelling at a speed $-v$ so in my rest frame the pen is travelling horizontally at velocity $-v$ and the fall looks like this:

[image: My frame]

But I still see the pen take the same time to fall to the ground as you do. That means the horizontal velocity does not affect the time the object takes to fall vertically.

Comment: But can you explain how you consider -v in your rest frame...?

Comment: Is it because you took +V direction upwards...?

Comment: @NehalSamee: It is because John likes to face forwards when travelling and has a positive outlook ;-)

Comment: Cam I say that while you are flying with velocity "V" , I throw the pen with velocity "V" too.So in your frame, you will see that the pen is static and gradually falling downwards ..?How can I interprete this situation?

Comment: @NehalSamee I've extended my answer to make it clearer what I mean

Comment: @JohnRennie is it only based on your thought that you say, you  measure similar time in your frame...?

Comment: @NehalSamee in Newtonian mechanics there is just a single global time for everyone. All observers will agree on the time the object was dropped, and the time it hits the ground. So all observers will agree on the time the object takes to fall.

Comment: @JohnRennie, but isn't the corresponding implication that the velocity of the ball is not constant in both frames? In the second diagram, it clearly travels a longer path in an equal amount of time - and if you extrapolated backwards using a constant velocity, then they would not agree on the time the ball was dropped?

Comment: @Steve: The velocity of the ball is not constant in any frame, because the ball is accelerating downwards so the vertical velocity $v_y$ changes according to $v_y = gt = \sqrt{2gs}$. Both observers agree on the value of $v_y$, but they disagree about the horizontal component $v_x$. For the observer who drops the ball $v_x=0$ while for the other observer $v_x = -v$. The total velocity is $v_t = \sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2}$ so the two observers also disagree about the total velocity.

Comment: @JohnRennie, indeed, but if they each maintained that total velocity was constant (as a mutual convention), wouldn't they instead disagree about where and when the ball was thrown/caught (rather than agreeing on those things and disagreeing about velocity)?

Comment: @Steve: I struggle to see how that makes sense. The ball is moving horizontally relative to one observer but not relative to the other observer. The two observers cannot agree that the velocity is the same. If you wanted to discuss this further we should probably continue [in the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).